# Akka stream difference between map( T => Future[U]) and flatMapConcat( T => Source.fromFuture(Future[U]))

Tags: akka, akka-stream

Please, what is the difference between those two approaches defining a Sink[RandomCdr,Future[Done]

```
Flow[RandomCdr]
      .grouped(bulkSize)
      .flatMapConcat{ (bulk : Seq[RandomCdr]) =>
        Source.fromFuture(collection.flatMap(_.insert[RandomCdr](false)(randomCdrWriter,ec).many(bulk)(ec))(ec))
      }
      .toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.right)


Flow[RandomCdr]
  .grouped(bulkSize)
  .map((bulk : Seq[RandomCdr]) => collection.flatMap(_.insert[RandomCdr](false)(randomCdrWriter,ec).many(bulk)(ec))(ec))
  .toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.right)
```

The function `collection.flatMap(_.insert[RandomCdr](false)(randomCdrWriter,ec).many(bulk)(ec))(ec)` that returns a Future[T] is the reactivemongo driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First snippet**

Here each incoming bulk will be transformed into a `Future`, and said `Future` will be run within the execution context you provide. Only at this point, the next bulk will be processed by generating another `Future`, and so on.

Basically the futures are run in sequence. This is similar in behaviour to

```
Flow[RandomCdr]
      .grouped(bulkSize)
      .mapAsync(parallelism = 1){ (bulk : Seq[RandomCdr]) =>
        collection.flatMap(_.insert[RandomCdr](false)(randomCdrWriter,ec).many(bulk)(ec))(ec)
      }
      .toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.right)
```

**Second snippet**

Here each incoming bulk will be transformed into a `Future`, which will be run within the execution context you provide. The `Future` will be then immediately passed to the `Sink.ignore` and its reference will be thrown away.

With this approach there is no control around how many `Future`s will be run at the same time. For this reason this approach is not recommended.

If you're looking for improved parallelism, consider using `mapAsync` as shown above, and tweak the parallelism parameter.

Comment: Does that mean the second snippet doesn't provide backpressure ?

Comment: Correct, it will fire as many future as it can with no backpressure